# How to plot Json data into Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, google-maps

The Below is my JSON Format.

```
{
"Data": {
"-template": "Parallax",
"Explore": {
  "IslandLife": {
    "TourismLocation": [
      {
        "Title": "Langkawi",
        "Latitude": "6.350000",
        "Longitude": "99.800000",
        "YouTubePlaylistID": "UUnTJRksbHP4O8JSz00_XRQA",
        "VideosList": {
          "YouTubeVideoID": [
            "7HlMpaSspNs",
            "tzeRnbd77HU",
            "VkIAbDIVJCA",
            "ksJ6kwTe9wM"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Title": "Rawa Island",
        "Latitude": "2.520278",
        "Longitude": "103.975833",
        "YouTubePlaylistID": "UUnTJRksbHP4O8JSz00_XRQA",
        "VideosList": { "YouTubeVideoID": "Kx0dUWaALKo" }
      },
      {
        "Title": "Perhentian Island",
        "Latitude": "5.903788",
        "Longitude": "102.753737",
        "YouTubePlaylistID": "UUnTJRksbHP4O8JSz00_XRQA",
        "VideosList": {
          "YouTubeVideoID": [
            "ZpcdGk5Ee0w",
            "TQTDOGpflZY"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Title": "Sabah Marine Park",
        "Latitude": "4.623326",
        "Longitude": "118.719800",
        "YouTubePlaylistID": "UUnTJRksbHP4O8JSz00_XRQA",
        "VideosList": { "YouTubeVideoID": "VCDTEKOqpKg" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
  }
}
```

and using Below this function i am retriving data from Json

```
$.getJSON('json/explore.json', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation.length; i++) {
       console.log(val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i].Title);
        console.log(val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i].Description);
         console.log(val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i].Latitude);
         console.log(val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i].Longitude);
        console.log(val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i].YouTubePlaylistID);
    }
  });
 });
```

So how to plot "Latitude" and "Longitude" into Double Dimensial array ??

I want my Array Object like this  ??

```
var locations = [
['Langkawi', 6.350000, 99.800000, 4],
['Rawa Island', 2.520278, 103.975833, 3],
['Perhentian Island', 5.903788, 102.753737, 2],
['Sabah Marine Park', 4.623326, 118.719800, 1]
];
```

Thanx in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var locations = [];

$.getJSON('json/explore.json', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation.length; i++) {
       var currLoc = val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation[i];
       locations.push([currLoc.Title, currLoc.Latitude, currLoc.Longitude];
    }
  });
});

console.log(locations);
```

But I can't imagine where do you retrieve the `4`<sup>th</sup> element of every array: if it is a reversed counter, you may change into

```
...
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var t = val.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation,
        tLen = t.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < tLen; i++) {
       var currLoc = t[i];
       locations.push([currLoc.Title, currLoc.Latitude, currLoc.Longitude, (tLen - i)]);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this one

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i,item)
{

    // item.Explore etc etc

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the data and then iterate over the `TourismLocation` object, adding the values to an array, and then pushing that array to the containing array :

```
$.getJSON('json/explore.json', function(data) {
    var locations = [];
    $.each(data.Data.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation, function(key, val) {
        var loc = [val.Title, val.Latitude, val.Longitude];
        locations.push(loc);
    });
    // use "locations" here, async and all
});
```

Also note that ajax is asynchronous, so you can't use the newly created array outside the callback function, as it's not available yet.

Not sure what the fourth item in the array is either, but if it's just a number iterating in reverse, you can add that as well :

```
$.getJSON('json/explore.json', function(data) {
    var locations = [],
        num = data.Data.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation.length;

    $.each(data.Data.Explore.IslandLife.TourismLocation, function(key, val) {
        var loc = [val.Title, val.Latitude, val.Longitude, num--];
        locations.push(loc);
    });
    // use "locations" here, async and all
});
```